# Send and receive images with aSmack on Android

Tags: android, xmpp, smack, asmack

I began to study the XMPP Protocol and trying to make a client for Android.
How to use asmack send and receive images?

Comment: I think that file transfer -might- be broken in aSmack, but don't take my word for it. If it is, you can convert your image to a `Base64`-`String` and send that.

Comment: Were you able to do it? If yes can you please share the code

Comment: Please consider marking your question as answered if you find an answer helpful.

Answer (score 4):

You can send images with aSmack just like you would send any other file with Smack. How to use XMPP file transfer with Smack is documented in the Section "File Transfer" at http://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/smack/docs/latest/documentation/extensions/

Be sure to use an up to date version of asmack to get In-Band Bytestreams support.